# Dataverse plugin - Getting `SandboxFault.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty: entityName`

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dataverse

I am developing a Dataverse plugin that creates an entity based on some input.

During execution I get the following error:

```json
{
  "code": "0x80040265",
  "message": "SandboxFault.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty: entityName. CorrelationId: ec5992f9-6a2b-424e-b5fb-c19a84572bcf"
}
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are not passing `EntityLogicalName` to the base constructor of `Entity`.

Your proxy class should contain a default constructor that passes the entity's logical name to its super class.

```cs
[EntityLogicalName(EntityLogicalName)]
public class SomeEntity : Entity
{
    public const string EntityLogicalName = "some_name";

    public SomeEntity()
        : base(EntityLogicalName) // pass the logical name
    {
    }
}
```